# Eco touring/diving in Malaysia

Tags: diving, ecotourism, malaysia

I've been SCUBA diving in KotaKina Balu. It was my intent to go to Sipidan, but couldn't make it, so I stayed in KKB. I'm looking at a return trip to Malaysia for some more diving, but also want an area with some eco-touring, **without** returning to northern Borneo. Does anyone have any knowledge of where in Malaysia that has good eco-tourism and SCUBA? I will also consider Brunei.

Comment: For any closing votes, I would appreciate a reason. I personally see a reason to close this, but I would like more input

Comment: related http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/11210/are-there-good-dive-spots-easily-accessible-from-kuala-lumpur-without-flying  - Perhentian Islands, Tioman island, & Redang islands are mentioned

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I suggest the [Perhentian Islands](http://wikitravel.org/en/Perhentian_Islands). It's off the east coast of west Malaysia (so not Borneo) and is relatively less frequented by tourists. Access is easy from the town of Kota Bharu - part of the Jungle Railway route - from where it takes 1.5 hours by taxi (or slightly longer by public bus) to reach Kuala Besut. A speedboat ride should cost about 60 MYR and take you in an hour to wherever you want to be dropped off on the islands.

Comment: Excellent. Thanks for the link. This looks like a wonderful area.

Answer (score 6):

Had you try [Tioman Island](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tioman_Island)? It's located at Southern part of West Malaysia.

Comment: Perhentian Islands seems to fit my needs better, however Tioman also looks wonderful. +1 for have a landing strip!

Answer (score 3):

Though honestly, none of the dive sites in peninsular Malaysia are even remotely close to the mindblowing beauty of Sipadan. Then some eco-tourism on the Kinabatangan river (saw live wild Orang Oetang there) and there really is no reason not to go back to the Eastern tip of Borneo.

If you really prefer peninsular Malaysia, the east side has better diving. Tioman and Perhentian are the two most famous spots.